# Animate HTML5 Element being Removed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which makes a rectangular surface appear and reappear on clicking. Clicking the button one time makes the "home_card" appear, clicking it again makes it disappear. The appearing effect functions at it should, I have a problem with animating the surface when it is being removed.

I am trying to use an eventlistener on the home_card element and then only remove the element on 'transitionend'. This is the way I read it should be done, but I am still doing something wrong. Can anyone spot the error?

My javascript file is the following:

```
function card_AppearsHome() {


if (transition_counter == 1){

    HOW CAN I INSERT A "DISAPPEARING TRANSITION" before removing the element? I know you can use an eventlistener for the "ontransitionend" event, but not how you can do it.. 

    document.getElementById("white_background_top").removeChild(home_card);
    transition_counter = 0;
}

else {

    //card/ div is created and appears, need to select a tranform: transition method 
    home_card = document.createElement('div');
    home_card.id = "home_card";
    home_card.className = "homecard_appear"

    document.getElementById("white_background_top").appendChild(home_card);

    transition_counter = 1;
}
}
```

This is the code in CSS with first the functioning appearing effect..

```
/* card appearing effect */
.homecard_appear{
animation-name: card_app_anim;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* standard transition */
@keyframes card_app_anim {
from {left: 54vw;}
to {left: 94vw;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 transition */
@-webkit-keyframes card_app_anim {
from {left: 54vw;}
to {left: 94vw;}
}
```

This is the code in CSS for the disappearing effect, I cannot wrap my head around how to do it properly in the Javascript file..

```
/* card disappearing effect */
.homecard_dissappear{
animation-name: card_dis_anim;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* standard transition */
@keyframes card_dis_anim {
from {left: 94vw;}
to {left: 54vw;}
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 transition */
@-webkit-keyframes card_dis_anim {
from {left: 94vw;}
to {left: 54vw;}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to listen for the `onanimationend` event.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (replace the code section where you ask the question with it):

```js
if (transition_counter === 1) {
  const home_card = document.querySelector('#homeCard');
  home_card.addEventListener('onanimationend', function() {
    home_card.remove();
    transition_counter = 0;
  });
  home_card.classList.add('homecard_dissappear');
}
```

It adds an event listener for `onanimationend` (which removes the element and resets your `transition_counter`) and adds the `homecard_dissappear` class (which initiates the transition). When transition ends, the event fires, the function is run.

Consider updating the question with a minimal reproducible example if you have any trouble implementing, and i'll update my answer.

---

Initially my example wrongly used `ontransitionend` (suggested in the question) and revolved around providing the syntax of adding an event listener, as that seemed to be OP's main issue.

However, as well pointed by folo and Hitesh Lala in the comments, the above animation will **not** trigger `ontransitionend`, as it doesn't contain any `transition`. Therefore, the proper event to bind to is `onanimationend`.

Comment: instead of `ontransitionend` it should be `onanimationend`, like Hitesh mentioned in the original post above. you also might want to polyfill the event, example: https://gist.github.com/webcyou/a1093f2f1b4533cf3f7a

Comment: @folo, you're correct. Since OP didn't bother creating a [mcve], I didn't test it. I try to stick to the following rule of thumb: don't put more effort into an answer than OP had put into researching the question.

Comment: That sounds wise ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I tried the above code but still not working. You did pointed me towards onanimationend, thank you for that! Sorry for not having a minimal reproducable example, it was very late last night.. I have added my progress another answer :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! Apparently I need to move my iteration to another question, so is the code of StackOverflow. So I did, you can find it now on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518327/addeventlistener-does-not-fire-in-javascript

Comment: The problem lie in the browser type..                                                                  
                                                                                                                            
 // Chrome, Safari and Opera use

element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", myEndFunction);

// Firefox uses                                                                                                                                                            
element.addEventListener("animationend", myEndFunction);