# addEventListener does not fire in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which makes a rectangular surface appear and reappear on clicking. Clicking the button one time makes the "home_card" appear, clicking it again makes it disappear. The appearing effect functions at it should, I have a problem with animating the surface when it is being removed.

The HTML code - script is called "side_menu.js", since the animation is part of a larger script with multiple functions in it. The appearing and disappearing of the card is linked to a "submit" button.

The first part of the CSS is the markup for the card.. The following three parts are for the entry animation of the card. This is functioning as it should. The last three parts are for the removal animation of the card. This is also functioning as it should, so this part of the code is correct.

The Javascript code is part of the script I am running that is responsible for creating and removing the card. The entry effect is doing what it should do, the removal effect not. The card is created and animated. When pushing the button again, the card removal animation is called, but at the end the card 'home_card' is not being removed. The 'onanimationend' event does not fire, nothing in the console. The removal line itself does function, it is really the event that does not fire!

```js
var transition_counter;
var home_card;

function card_AppearsHome() {

  if (transition_counter == 1) {

    home_card.className = 'homecard_dissappear';

    //When using the css transition use transitionend, and when using keyframes/animation, use animationend.
    home_card.addEventListener('onanimationend', function() {

      document.getElementById('white_background_top').removeChild(home_card);
      transition_counter = 0;

      //animationend event is not firing 
      //it does not find the home_card, onclick is not working either 
      console.log("check animationend");
    });

    transition_counter = 0;
  } else {

    home_card = document.createElement('div');
    home_card.id = "home_card";
    home_card.className = "homecard_appear"
    document.getElementById("white_background_top").appendChild(home_card);
    transition_counter = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
/* Markup for the card created dynamically */

#home_card {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vh;
  left: 54vw;
  top: 25vh;
  background-color: #000;
}


/* card appearing effect */

.homecard_appear {
  animation-name: card_app_anim;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


/* standard animation */

@keyframes card_app_anim {
  from {
    left: 54vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 94vw;
  }
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 animation */

@-webkit-keyframes card_app_anim {
  from {
    left: 54vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 94vw;
  }
}


/* card disappearing effect */

.homecard_dissappear {
  animation-name: card_dis_anim;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


/* standard animation */

@keyframes card_dis_anim {
  from {
    left: 94vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 54vw;
  }
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 animation */

@-webkit-keyframes card_dis_anim {
  from {
    left: 94vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 54vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="white_background_top">

  <input type="submit" class="transition_submit" value="Transition" onclick="card_AppearsHome()">

</div>
```

The error is in the code

```
home_card.addEventListener('onanimationend', function() {}
```

The eventlistener does not fire, nothing in the console.. I think it does not find the home_card object, since also other eventlisteners do not fire. Onclick does not function either. I am missing something, but do not know what. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the correct EventListener by browser

```
// Chrome, Safari and Opera

element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", myEndFunction);

// Firefox
element.addEventListener("animationend", myEndFunction);
```